# d3 rect not rendering in map - react

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Super new to react, and trying to do some simple d3 exercises in react but for some reason it's not rendering the `<rect/>` tag. Not sure whether there's something wrong with my `map` function. There's no error anywhere tho.

here's my code:

```
class Casing extends React.Component{

render(){

    let y = this.props.y;
    let wrid = this.props.wrid;
    let wellSection = this.props.wellSection;

    function casingPositionX(index){
        return (110 + (50 * index));
    }

    function casingPositionY(depthTvdFrom){        
        return y(depthTvdFrom);
    }

    function casingHeight(depthTvdFrom,depthTvdTo){
        return (y(depthTvdTo) - y(depthTvdFrom));
    }

    return(
        <g 
            className=""
            name={wrid ? "casing_" + wrid : ""}
        >

            {wrid &&
                wellSection.map(function(section,i){
                    <rect
                        name={"casing_section[" + (section.section) + "]"}
                        fill=""
                        width="2"
                        height={casingHeight(section.DepthTvdFrom, section.DepthTvdTo)}
                        transform={"translate(" + casingPositionX(i) + "," + casingPositionY(i) + ")"}
                    />

                })
            }
        </g>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the 'wrid' and 'wellSection' props have values passed and aren't empty? Also, `wellSection.map()` isn't returning anything in your code.

Comment: Always use a `key={}` prop in a element that is rendered by a map function.

Comment: @AnbarasiU yes. this class would not be call unless the data exist. Tho the function I called have data in all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when in React, if you're returning a html element, in need to be enclose inside a `return` bracket such as below

```
            wellSection.map(function(section,i){
                return (<rect
                    name={"casing_section[" + (section.section) + "]"}
                    fill=""
                    width="2"
                    height={casingHeight(section.DepthTvdFrom, section.DepthTvdTo)}
                    transform={"translate(" + casingPositionX(i) + "," + casingPositionY(i) + ")"}
                />)

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Casing component is enclosed inside a `<svg>` element?
Try to enclose the `<g>` element inside `<svg>`.

```
class Casing extends React.Component {

render() {
    let {y, wrid, wellSection} = this.props;

    function casingPositionX(index) {
        return (110 + (50 * index));
    }

    function casingPositionY(depthTvdFrom) {        
        return y(depthTvdFrom);
    }

    function casingHeight(depthTvdFrom,depthTvdTo) {
        return (y(depthTvdTo) - y(depthTvdFrom));
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <svg width="600" height="400">
            <g 
                className=""
                name={wrid ? "casing_" + wrid : ""}>
                {
                    wrid &&
                    wellSection.map(function(section,i) {
                        <rect
                            name={"casing_section[" + (section.section) + "]"}
                            fill=""
                            width="2"
                            height={casingHeight(section.DepthTvdFrom,                                     
                                section.DepthTvdTo)}
                            transform={"translate(" + casingPositionX(i) + "," + 
                                casingPositionY(i) + ")"}
                        />
                    })
                }
            </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    )
}
```